# Reverse lookup for loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop, reverse-lookup

I have a set of numbers / string that makes other number / string. I need to create a function that gives me a list of the all the numbers / string needed to create that number / string.

Consider the following dataset

```
ingredients <- c('N/A', 'cat', 'bird')
product <- c('cat', 'bird', 'dog')
data <- data.frame(ingredients, product)
head(data)
```

If I input function(dog), I would like a list that returns bird and then cat. The function knows when to stop when ingredients = N/A (there's nothing more to look up).

It seems like some of sort of for loop that appends is the right approach.

```
needed <- list()

for (product in list){

  needed[[product]]<-df
}

df <- dplyr::bind_rows(product)
```

Comment: corrected cause i'm dumb

Answer (score 0):

I appended your initial code to make `N/A` simply equal to `NA` so I could use the `is.na` function in my R code. Now the sample data is

```
ingredients <- c(NA, 'cat', 'bird')
product <- c('cat', 'bird', 'dog')
data <- data.frame(ingredients, product)
```

Code is below:

```
ReverseLookup <- function (input) {
  ans <- list()
  while (input %in% data$product) {
    if (!is.na(as.character(data[which(data$product == input),]$ingredients))) {
      ans <- append(ans, as.character(data[which(data$product == input),]$ingredients))
      input <- as.character(data[which(data$product == input),]$ingredients)
    }
    else {
       break
     }
  }
  print(ans)
}
```

I create an empty list and then create a `while` loop that just checks if the `input` exists in the `product` column. If so, it then checks to see if the corresponding `ingredient` to the `product` input is a non-NA value. If that's the case, the `ingredient` will be appended to `ans` and will become the new `input`. I also added a `break` statement to get out of the `while` loop when you reach an `NA`.

I did a quick test on the case where there is no `NA` in your dataframe and it appears to be working fine. Maybe someone else here can figure out a more concise way to write this, but it should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can likely find a way to use a tree of some type to work through nodes. But, using a recursive function in base R, I have come up with this.

I have also changed the 'N/A' to `NA` to make life easier. Also, I have added in `stringsAsFactors = F` to the data frame.

```
ingredients <- c(NA, 'cat', 'bird')
product <- c('cat', 'bird', 'dog')
data <- data.frame(ingredients, product, stringsAsFactors = F)

reverse_lookup <- function(data, x, last_result = NULL) {
  if (! is.null(last_result)) {
    x <- data[data$product == last_result[length(last_result)], "ingredients"]
  }

  if (! is.na(x)) {
    last_result <- reverse_lookup(data, x, c(last_result, x))
  }

  last_result
}
```

This returns the input as well, which you can always drop off as the first element of the vector.

```
> reverse_lookup(data, "dog")
[1] "dog"  "bird" "cat"
```